# CPU-efficient method of checking if array position is null in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

A program I've written needs to check millions of points in a 2D array to see if they are not null. Here is the code I am using:

```
Particle *particleGrid[1920][1080];
bool Sensor::checkForParticle(int x, int y) {
    if (x > 1920 || x < 0) return 0;
    if (y > 1080 || y < 0) return 0;
    if (mainController->particleGrid[x][y] != NULL) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This function uses the most CPU in the entire application (~70% of the application's CPU usage is due to this function), even more than my implementation of the Bresenham line drawing algorithm (the example function is called on every point of the line generated by the Bresenham algorithm). Is there a more CPU-efficient way to perform the null-checking operation?

Comment: *(~70% of the application's CPU usage is due to this function)*. **How do you know that?**

Comment: This question might be better suited for codereview. Anyways, is there a reaason why your x/y are signed? one unsgined comparison instead of two signed seems cheaper.

Comment: Just a side note: it should be `x >= 1920` and `y >= 1080`

Comment: If it is inside a loop is the loop what is taking that much time. Have you considered to inline this?

Comment: It sounds like this function isn't actually what is eating up your CPU time, but rather the function that is calling it in a tight loop.  You may be able to speed it up (if this is a sparse 2D matrix), by creating a cache table that holds the non-null indicies.  If the array is non-sparse, that won't help much, though.

Comment: beside any performance improvements in answers/other comments... are you sure you need to check every point on the line? if both start point and end point of a straight line are within your bounds then so are all the points in between. Unless most of your lines are outside the bounds you could save most of your processing by first checking the initial and end point only

Comment: It's an organism simulation - the organism's sensory data is obtained by drawing hundreds of lines in all directions around its body each frame - and if a line intersects with a particle in a particle simulation, it obtains sensory information about the particle. It's necessary for the program to check every single point along the line, otherwise it might miss a particle between the beginning and end point of the line. I'm using Instruments to profile the CPU usage of the application.

Comment: "the organism's sensory data is obtained by drawing hundreds of lines in all directions around its body each frame" it seems like you are trying to make a naive version of ray tracing, it is orthogonal to what  you are asking but a classic implementation of ray tracing might have better performance. Also, as I said before, if you inline the function you will be saving time spent on the function call

Comment: In case you are not familiar with ray tracing in the context of collision detection, this little article might be helpful http://www.flipcode.com/archives/Basic_Collision_Detection.shtml

Comment: I'll look into ray tracing and see if I can find a way to implement it in a way that's useful. Thank you for pointing me in that direction.

Comment: when you calculate the rays, would there be a way of saving the information of them? in my opinion it would be better to iterate over a vector of lines instead of the whole grid that might also be empty

Comment: The ray calculation uses little CPU due to the Bresenham line algorithm. There's a lot of dynamic information in the simulation - the organism moves, particles change location, etc. so it's not really useful to store information. The CPU usage issue arrises from simply checking if an index in an array is NULL. For whatever reason, doing that uses a ridiculous amount of CPU. I suppose pre-calculating the vectors of points in each line and then shifting the points to the location of the organism would save CPU in runtime, but it's the particleGrid[x][y] == NULL that slows everything down.

Answer (score 2):

If it is called in a loop, you could get away without checking the arguments.  It will also be faster row first as you're examining data close in memory location which will reduce cache hits.

Answer (score 2):

If you compare against unsigned literals, you get the check against 0 for free, because negative numbers end up very large when converted to unsigned. Also, you don't need all those ifs:

```
bool Sensor::checkForParticle(int x, int y)
{
    return (x < 1920u) && (y < 1080u)   // note both "u" suffixes for unsigned
        && (mainController->particleGrid[x][y] != NULL);
}
```

By the way, why do you have your array in column-major order? Are your outer loops on x or y? If they are on y, switching to row-major will dramatically improve the efficiency due to cache-friendliness:

```
Particle *particleGrid[1080][1920];

bool Sensor::checkForParticle(int x, int y)
{
    return (x < 1920u) && (y < 1080u)
        && (mainController->particleGrid[y][x] != NULL);   // note switched order
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the 2D array is sparse, something like this could help you speed up a tight loop:

```
Particle *particleGrid[1920][1080];

// somewhere before your tight loop
std::map<std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, Particle*> createCache()
{
    std::map<std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, Particle*> cache;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 1920; ++i)
    {
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < 1080; ++j)
        {
            if (mainController->particleGrid[i][j])
            {
                std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> coord = std::make_pair(i, j);
                cache[coord] = mainController->particleGrid[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return cache;
}

// then this is called in your tight loop
bool Sensor::checkForParticle(unsigned int x, unsigned int y, const std::map<std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, Particle*>& cache) 
{
    std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> coord = std::make_pair(x, y);
    return cache.find(coord) != map.end();
}
```

If it is not sparse, this will not help at all.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: hoist the consistency check out of the loop:

```
bool Sensor::uncheckedCheckForParticle(int x, int y) {
    return mainController->particleGrid[y][x];
}
```

If you really need to guard against sloppy programming, you could `assert()` in the function and/or guard the call site. I'd bet that this will *dramatically* improve performance.

Step 2: make the now trivial function `inline`.

Answer (score 0):

You could flatten the array from two-dimensional to one-dimensional (sadly, this may require refactoring elsewhere in the code though) :

```
Particle *particleGrid[1920 * 1080];
bool Sensor::checkForParticle(int x, int y) {
    return (mainController->particleGrid[x * 1080 + y] != NULL)
}
```